# Nodes put one on top of the other

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am a total beginner in tikz and I am using the following code (slight modification from texample.net) to draw 2 red black trees. The problem I am facing is that both trees are placed one on top of the other. Can you help me? What I am trying to do is to put them in the same height, one on the left and one on the right

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
    text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
    minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
     \node [arn_r] {15} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {5} edge from parent node[above left]
                         {$x$}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {20}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }                            
 ;   
    \node [arn_r] {47}
            child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
                            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {51}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }

; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want? You can use `tikzpicture` twice; one for each tree and insert them without empty line between. So the pictures will be on the same line. Use `\quad` between, for example. `....\end{tikzpicture} \quad
\begin{tikzpicture}....`

Comment: I have edited the question to be more understandable. I would prefer a solution using one picture, because I want more paths to be drawn, once the two trees are correctly drawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, just specify the coordinate to insert the root for the second tree.

For example

```
\node at (7,0) [arn_r]  {47}
```

[image]

**ps.** I suggest you to read [`tikz-qtree` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two more question though. When I put negative coordinates one the first (left) tree, it does not move further on the left but rather pushes the other tree on the right. Is that normal? And second, is there any difference in placing <at (7,0)> before or after the [arn_r] ?

Comment: @Paramar, for the 1st question, there is a coordinate system. To see where is the origin `(0,0)` just insert this `\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (2pt);`. Then you could see what is happening. For the 2nd question I **guess** that they are the same.